# Blank white screen after updating Angular from 7.3 to 13

Tags: angular

I really hope someone can help us.
I am new to Angular and got a project inherited.
I have an Angular project with version 7.3, which causes us troubles when we really try to work with it or to update it.
With version 7.3 the project is running so long as you dont add any packages or delete the node-modules file and run "npm i" for installing all dependencies/packages again. The results in these cases are a blank white screen when running the application.
So now we considered it a better idea to update the project to the newer version 13 of anuglar, so everything is up to date and that the handling will maybe be better.
The node version is 16.3.0, npm is version 8.1.3.

1. So I followed the instructions of the angular update guide: https://update.angular.io/
2. I deleted node_modules and package-lock.json serveral times an did "npm i --legacy-peer-deps" after that
3. I deleted  "es5BrowserSupport": true in angular.json
4. I added "enableIvy": true, "fullTemplateTypeCheck": false under "angularCompilerOptions" in the tsconfig.json
5. I added types/jest
6. In angular.modules I added "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" under Ng-Modules.schema

My current package.json file:

```
  "name": "webapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "type": "commonjs",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^12.0.0-beta.35",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^13.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
    "angular-plotly.js": "^1.1.0",
    "angular-resizable-element": "^4.0.0",
    "angular-resize-element": "^1.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "core-js": "^3.19.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "http-server": "^14.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.11",
    "ng-sidebar": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "plotly.js": "^1.45.2",
    "raphael": "^2.2.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^1.14.1",
    "util": "^0.12.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "13.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~13.0.0",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.40",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.9.5",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^6.3.7",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "typescript": ">=4.4.0 <4.5.0",
    "webpack": "~5.64.4",
    "webpack-cli": "~4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~4.5.0"
  },
  "description": "This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 7.3.0.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

My current tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "types" : ["node", "jest"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]


  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": false
  }
}
```

My tsconfig.app.json :

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

My tsconfig.spec.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

My terminal after "ng serve" :

```
 Browser application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files   | Names         |      Size
main.js               | main          | 943.59 kB
styles.css, styles.js | styles        | 370.39 kB
polyfills.js          | polyfills     | 164.77 kB
runtime.js            | runtime       |   1.32 kB

                      | Initial Total |   1.45 MB

Build at: 2021-12-02T10:14:14.625Z - Hash: d4934bcc2eb62a37 - Time: 27493ms

Warning: C:/Users/<...>/Documents/test/Software-Analytics/WebAngular/webapp/src/app/pre-analysis.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.

Warning: C:/Users/<...>/Documents/test/Software-Analytics/WebAngular/webapp/src/app/resizable.directive.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.

Warning: C:/Users/<...>/Documents/test/Software-Analytics/WebAngular/webapp/src/environments/environment.prod.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.



** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


√ Compiled successfully.
```

The output on the browser console:

```
[webpack-dev-server] Disconnected! polyfills.js:1:15309
[webpack-dev-server] Trying to reconnect... polyfills.js:1:15309
[webpack-dev-server] Live Reloading enabled. polyfills.js:1:15309
[webpack-dev-server] Warnings while compiling. polyfills.js:1:15374
[webpack-dev-server] WARNING
C:/Users/Leonie.Tischer/Documents/test/Software-Analytics/WebAngular/webapp/src/app/pre-analysis.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig. polyfills.js:1:15374
[webpack-dev-server] WARNING
C:/Users/Leonie.Tischer/Documents/test/Software-Analytics/WebAngular/webapp/src/app/resizable.directive.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig. polyfills.js:1:15374
[webpack-dev-server] WARNING
C:/Users/Leonie.Tischer/Documents/test/Software-Analytics/WebAngular/webapp/src/environments/environment.prod.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig. polyfills.js:1:15374
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    607 http://localhost:4200/main.js:1
    a http://localhost:4200/runtime.js:1
    185 http://localhost:4200/main.js:1
    a http://localhost:4200/runtime.js:1
    J http://localhost:4200/main.js:1
    <anonymous> http://localhost:4200/main.js:1
    n http://localhost:4200/runtime.js:1
    <anonymous> http://localhost:4200/main.js:1
```

I already tried to "Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig." , but I just got errors. Also tried to add a webpack.config.json file , but this didnt work either.

What do I miss?

Thank you for your help, it is really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Was the update from 7 to 8 successful, or did you go directly from 7 to 13?

Comment: I went right to 13, through the guide on the angular webpage

Comment: It can be tricky to skip major versions during the update for larger apps - the guide has: `Warning: We do not support migrating across multiple major versions at once. Please migrate each major version individually.`

Comment: Ah sorry, my answer was not clear. I updated step by step. from 7 to 8, from 8 to 9 and so on. But i did not control if the application was running in the new version, was this a huge error? do i have to do this again?

Comment: I don't think you'd need to start again. Maybe have a look at the answer from Dieter - if you create a separate Angular 13 project and compare the angular.json, tsconfig's, dependencies etc you might spot something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had to upgrade a large application from version 7 to 12 with many lazy loaded modules implemented in seperate angular libaries (in separate GIT-repos).
I had so much troubles using ng update (many weird compiler errors) so that I had to update this way:

- installed angular cli version 12 globally
- updated nodejs
- For the application and each library I created a new angular project from scratch using the new version of the angular cli.
- then I copied the original source code to the new generated project, added missing dependencies and npm-scripts to package.json
- If I remember correctly, in version 7 angular created a file public_api.ts (in libararies only) and angular 12 now creates a public-api.ts (so rename your original public_api.ts to public-api.ts!)
- Since strictMode is now default, you might get a lot of compile-errors. Either try to fix those errors (if you have enough time) or deactivate strictMode in tsconfig.json (change compilerOptions/strict and angularCompilerOptions/strictTemplates to false). For strictMode see more at https://indepth.dev/posts/1402/bulletproof-angular or https://javascript.plainenglish.io/why-angular-strict-mode-is-a-game-changer-11a0ce62f3aa.

This was the easiest and most reliable way for me to update skipping so many versions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, indeed i have already tried it. i just got so many errors, that i shyed away from it.   for example:   ```Property 'api' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; }'. ``` And it doesnt recognize some links :  ```Error: Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
C:\Users\Leonie.Tischer\Documents\test\webpacktest\webpacktest\src\app\pre-analysis\pre-analysis.component.css:10:12: Can't resolve '../../assets/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf' in 'C:\Users\Leonie.Tischer\Documents\test\webpacktest\webpacktest\src\app\pre-analysis' ```

Comment: for the error: ```Property 'api' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; }'. ```   I dont find a public_api.ts file.

Comment: Ok, this is most likely caused by the typescript strict-mode (which is now activated by default, which wasn't the case in angular 7). I forgot to mention that in my answer:

Try to change the tsconfig.json in the project (change  compilerOptions/strict and angularCompilerOptions/strictTemplates to false).

Comment: Regarding the error  

Can't resolve '../../assets/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf':  

IMHO you did not copy everything correctly.  '../../assets/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf' is a relative path to C:\Users\Leonie.Tischer\Documents\test\webpacktest\webpacktest\src\app\pre-analysis'.

Does the file 

C:\Users\Leonie.Tischer\Documents\test\webpacktest\webpacktest\assets\iconfont\MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf 

exist?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  It was a mistake when copying, yes. I really didnt see it.   But sadly i got still the api error, and i dont find any solution for it. I dont discover an issue where it popped up so far. strict: false and so on, did not solve it.